# How to change Tomcat 8.5 log folder

Tags: tomcat, logging, path

I am running Tomcat 8.5 on a Red Hat 7.5 server, I have a server application which logs in $CATALINA_HOME/logs, I need to change the directory where tomcat logs everything, I have found how to change catalina.out path and other logs but I need to change all logs.

I have tried the following;

1. loggin.properties file, but it only change some files but no every one.
2. $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh but it only changes catalina.out.

Is there any form to change all logs that are saved on $CATALINA_HOME/logs to another path?

Thank you.

Comment: You could remove the logs directory and use a symbolic link to the directory you want.

Comment: I have done this and it worked well, but i still have the curiosity about if its posible to do this from some config file. Thank you for the help!

Comment: that's why I commented and didn't answer. I hope someone answers.